# Eager-loading in Rails 3.1 controller action which responds_to json

Tags: jqgrid, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event

  # use default_scope so shows are ordered by date by default
  default_scope order("date ASC")
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shows, :dependent => :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  scope :future, lambda { includes(:shows).joins(:shows).where("shows.date > ?", Date.today).group("event_id") }

  def start_date
    shows.first.date
  end

  def end_date
    shows.last.date
  end

  def ends_in_future?
    end_date > Date.today
  end
end
```

I would like to create a controller action to use with jqGrid. So far using `Event.includes(:shows).all.to_a` returns all the shows in the JSON string, but I can't get hold of `start_date` and `end_date`, which is kinda understandable. Is it possible to have derived/calculated properties rendered in JSON?

I also notice the shows for each event are not in the JSON string. Is there any way I can get all the events, complete with child shows entities, rendered in the JSON string?

Many thanks,
Dany.

EDIT: Partially solved this by using `as_json(:include => :shows)` in the controller action. This returns the event and all the associated shows for each event. The only thing remaining is to figure out how I can include `start_date` and `end_date` in the json string...

EDIT: Here was my original controller action code - it may not be the best code since I'm still feeling my way around Rails:

```
matches = Event.includes(:shows).all
respond_to do |format|
   format.json {render :json => matches.as_json(:include => :shows)}
end
```

As it turned out I don't have to run the query first - it can just be part of responding to the json request. I should've read the as_json specs a lot closer first! Here's the solution in my controller action:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => Event.all.as_json(:include => :shows, :methods => [:start_date, :end_date])}
end
```

That renders everything, including the "derived" method. Unfortunately that seems to generate a lot of queries. This provides the json string I want, but is it the best way? Would love to hear any improved methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can get those columns selected into the Event record like so:

```
Event.includes(:shows).joins(:shows).select("events.*, MIN(shows.date) as start_date, MAX(shows.date) as end_date").all
```

You may need to alias those columns by a different name (e.g. 'show_start_date', 'show_end_date') because the Event records will already have start_date and end_date methods that you've defined. You'll have to work around that method name collision.

Comment: I'm adding my controller code in the question to clarify it further

Comment: I've achieved the desired json string, as described in my edited answer - but getting it doesn't feel quite right...